# Can't set user_id field when creating a new object, using a belong_to / has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, haml

Using rails 3.2 & ruby 2.1

Here my models

```
class CheckoutRent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :rent_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :rent

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checkout_rent

  ...
end
```

My controller

```
class CheckoutRentsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      @checkout_rent = current_user.checkout_rent.new
      @checkout_rent.save
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'Veuillez vous connecter.'
    end
  end
end
```

My views

```
= form_for(@checkout_rent) do |f|  
  .field
    = f.select :rent_id, Rent.all.collect{|c| [c.user.name, c.id]}  
  .field
    = f.label :comment
    %br/
    = f.text_field :comment
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

All is fine except that user_id is not set when creating a new checkout_rent.

In console: CheckoutRent.last.user_id  return nil

Answer (score 2):

Your user model has_many checkout_rent, so in your controller you should have:

```
@checkout_rent = current_user.checkout_rents.create
```

note the plural checkout_rents (as you have it now it should fail), also note that create replaces new + save, so you can erase this line:

```
@checkout_rent.save
```

EDIT:

I also suggest you modify the following line to follow the conventions:

```
has_many :checkout_rents
```

Comment: Thanks,
the relation is well done:
 User.last.checkoutRent works but CheckoutRent.last.user_id is nill.

Comment: If you go to the console and type: 'User.last.checkout_rents.new', does that new object have a user_id? (when you don't follow the conventions some unexpected behaviour may occur)